# Google Sheets. I'm trying to insert a row of CheckBoxes IF B2 Cell has text

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

The trick part is... i can't figure out a way to do it, the formulas don't let you add checkboxes. I tried using the code from Google Script to insert a Checkbox but *nonetheless* i get nowhere. Please, i need help to work here T_T

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to make checkboxes appear is to insert them to all rows beforehand, and make them invisible with a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule that sets the text color of the checkbox cells to white when there is no text in column `B`.

An invisible checkbox cannot be toggled accidentally.

For the range `C2:Z`, a suitable conditional formatting custom formula rule would be like `=isblank($B2)`.

Comment: I just tried it and it halfway worked. This idea was fantastic, the only problem i had is that the invisible checkbox CAN be toggled accidentally as the formula changes from False to True. Anyways i will stick to this idea since i don't have any better ones, Thanks!